# Why does Visual Studio open decoratedxaml in debug folder than opening my actual xaml when there is a syntax error failing the build

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Universal App. I use Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

If I have made syntactical mistakes or used a converter without declaring it's namespace at the top, VS points out errors when trying to build as usual.

But when I click on the error to Navigate to the line that is causing the error.
Instead of opening my actual xaml page residing \Pages, it opens the xaml page in \obj\x86\Debug\decoratedxaml\Pages

However this is not consistent, for some errors it opens the actual file and the decoratedxaml for some others.

This causes problems like me trying to edit the decoratedxaml by mistake and when trying to build again, the build fails and decoratedxaml will be modified to the previous version by Visual Studio.

Is this expected behavior?
Also is there a setting which I can enable so that it will always open the actual file.

I would be glad if someone can guide me in the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you by any chance using XamlSpy?